# How much revenue does a team make for a playoff game?

Tags: nba, finances, postseason

Before the 2013 NBA playoffs, many people speculated that the Miami Heat would go 16-0 (e.g. sweep every series) en route to their 2nd straight title.  As I watched the Miami Heat trounce the Indiana Pacers in game 7 of the 2013 Eastern Conference Finals, it seemed apparent that they definitely had the capability to do so.  I then thought of what is most certainly a ridiculous but nevertheless interesting idea.  What if the Heat players were instructed to lose in order to have more home games, e.g. increase revenue.  (*This is not my question, so please don't answer that!*)

I agree, there's no way a group of professional athletes would even risk such a thing, but it got me wondering, **how much revenue does a team make for a playoff game?**  I know it's driven largely by ticket cost and arena size, but is there any per-team data available?

(FWIW: [This article](http://www.miaminewtimes.com/2012-01-12/news/miami-heat-s-micky-arison-keeps-american-airlines-arena-profits/full/) paints Heat owner Micky Arison in a pretty selfish light, so perhaps my conspiracy theory isn't far off ;) )

Comment: not to fuel the conspiracy theory, but game 7s also get incredible TV ratings (in all sports)

Comment: @waxeagle you make a great point.  In fact, I think revenue from TV deals might even surpass that of net ticket revenue.

Comment: it's possible that for the playoffs this is true. However typically the TV deals are static amounts and not dependent on the number of games. So it benefits ESPN/TNT/ABC but not the NBA directly for them to have more playoff games.

Answer (score 4):

On [ticket sales *alone*](http://wagesofwins.com/2013/03/28/the-best-nba-markets-of-2012-13/) in 2012-13 the Heat made 1.44 million *per game*. That said, the average NBA fan spends something like and additional $25 (the numbers for cost I see seem to indicate that it's tickets for 4 + ~$100 which then divided 4 ways gives us $25). The Heat regularly sell out regular season games and I'm sure they fill to capacity for these playoff games. The max capacity for their arena is listed at [19,600](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Airlines_Arena). Which puts combined concessions and parking at around half a million dollars per game.

That means their revenue including concessions and parking comes in at least 2 million dollars per game (this is low considering they raise average ticket prices for playoff games).

This suggests that by playing 2 extra home playoff games the heat brought in an additional 4 million dollars in revenue.

However, this doesn't necessarily directly benefit the Heat. They are subject to a revenue sharing agreement with the league and as much as 30% of their profits [may be shared](http://www.cbafaq.com/salarycap.htm#Q24).

Comment: However, revenue varies wildly between teams based on ticket and concession prices and also significantly on arena capacity.